# How to display 'selected' value of dropdown in Laravel Blade template used for both edit/create?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Blade templating in a Laravel 4 view to display a form for both create and edit, it all works fine until I have to render a `select` input type - it's ok when editing, but when creating a new record I get an error message `Undefined variable: data`, which is triggered by the 'selected' value in the second last line (last parameter passed to `Form::select()`)

```
@if( isset( $data) )
    {{ Form::model( $data ) }}
@else
    {{ Form::open() }}
@endif

    {{ Form::label( 'foo', 'label text' ) }}
    {{ Form::select( 'foo' , array('0' => 'No', '1' => 'Yes'), $data->foo ); }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

is there a standard way in Laravel to avoid this when `$data` is not defined, using model binding as I have so far? Or do I need to simply use a variable to check in advance if `$data` is not undefined?

Comment: Actually, with model binding, you should be able to just remove the `$data->foo` part. The value will be set according to the name (`foo`) of the select.

Comment: ah! brilliant, I am new to laravel and I didn't know that. You should post this as an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole purpose of [Form Model Binding](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#form-model-binding) is that you don't have to set the values on your input fields yourself. You can just leave the value argument blank and Laravel will fill the value(s) in based on the `name` of the select, input, etc.

```
{{ Form::select( 'foo' , array('0' => 'No', '1' => 'Yes')); }}
```

Also you can even remove your `isset($data)` check because Laravel will do that as well:

```
{{ Form::model( $data ) }}
    {{ Form::label( 'foo', 'label text' ) }}
    {{ Form::select( 'foo' , array('0' => 'No', '1' => 'Yes')); }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```